# Why can't I run dtruss against this executable?

Tags: terminal, dtrace

```
Darwin ME 19.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Tue Jun 22 19:49:55 PDT 2021; root:xnu-6153.141.35~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Im trying to run an executable with dtruss. Even when removing code signing I get failure. The error message is not helpful.

```
codesign --remove-signature ./bin/gcloud
sudo dtruss ./bin/gcloud --help
dtrace: failed to execute ./bin/gcloud: (os/kern) failure
```